# citing meta-analytic sources in papaja

Tags: r-markdown, papaja

I'm writing up a meta-analysis and I would like to cite papers from the meta-analysis in the bibliography with an asterisks before the last name. I'm able to use the nocite function in the reference section to include references not cited in the text, but I need to also add the asterisks denoting that it's from the MA. I see that the apacite package has a function called \nocitemeta, but this doesn't seem to work here.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of two ways to achieve this, both only work with PDF documents (i.e., `apa6_pdf()`). **Update**: I have added a `pandoc-citeproc` approach below which I would recommend because it requires no new syntax and works for PDF and Word documents.

## 1. `apacite`

The first approach utilizes the `apacite` package and thereby enables the use of `\nocitemeta`. The downside to this approach is that, as far as I know, you need to deactivate `pandoc-citeproc` by setting `pandoc: no`. This causes the common `pandoc-citeproc` citation syntax (e.g., `@R-papaja`) to be ignored. You need to use the `apacite` syntax throughout your document.

````
---
title             : "The title"
shorttitle        : "Title"

author: 
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"

affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "Wilhelm-Wundt-University"

bibliography      : ["r-references.bib"]
citeproc          : no

header-includes   :
  - \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
  - \bibliographystyle{apacite}
  - \renewcommand{\APACmetastar}{\ensuremath{{}^\ast}}

documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "man"

output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
---

```{r}
library("papaja")
```

\nocitemeta{R-base}

This works: \citet{R-papaja}

This doesn't work: @R-papaja

```{r create-r-references}
r_refs(file = "r-references.bib")
```

\bibliography{r-references.bib}
````

## 2. `biblatex`

The second approach, inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156737/11001), relies on `biblatex` and introduces a custom command that mimics `\nocitemeta` from `apacite`. The advantage here is that the `pandoc-citeproc` citation syntax still works.

````
---
title             : "The title"
shorttitle        : "Title"

author: 
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"
    corresponding : yes    # Define only one corresponding author
    address       : "Postal address"
    email         : "my@email.com"

affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "Wilhelm-Wundt-University"

bibliography      : ["r-references.bib"]
biblio-style      : "apa"

header-includes:
  - \DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
  - \DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}
  - \renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\ifcategory{asterisk}{\ensuremath{{}^\ast}}{}}
  - \newcommand*{\nocitemeta}[1]{\nocite{#1}\addtocategory{asterisk}{#1}}

output:
  papaja::apa6_pdf:
    citation_package: biblatex
---


```{r}
library("papaja")
```

\nocitemeta{R-base}

Now this works: @R-papaja

```{r create-r-references}
r_refs(file = "r-references.bib")
```

\defbibnote{asterisk}{References marked with an asterisk indicate studies included in the meta-analysis.}
\printbibliography[title=References,prenote=asterisk]
\renewcommand{\printbibliography}{}
````

## 3. `pandoc-citeproc`

By modifying the default APA CSL file, it is possible to display an asterisk (or another indicator) in front of select bibliography entries.

**Update**: `papaja` now supports this approach out of the box (see [the manual](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/writing.html#meta-analysis-references)). For the previous manual approach skip the following.

To active bibliography annotation set `annotate_references: yes`

````
---
title             : "The title"
shorttitle        : "Title"

author:
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"

bibliography      : ["r-references.bib"]
annotate_references: yes
nocite            : |
  @R-base

output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
---

```{r}
library("papaja")
```

@R-papaja

\newpage

# References

```{r create_r-references}
r_refs(file = "r-references.bib")
```

\begingroup
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.5in}
References marked with an asterisk indicate studies included in the meta-analysis.
<div id = "refs"></div>
\endgroup
````

The edited BibTeX file `r-references.bib` looks like this (note the `annotation` field for `R-base`:

```
@Manual{R-base,
  title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
  author = {{R Core Team}},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  address = {Vienna, Austria},
  year = {2018},
  url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
  annote = {*}
}
@Manual{R-papaja,
  author = {Frederik Aust and Marius Barth},
  title = {{papaja}: {Create} {APA} manuscripts with {R Markdown}},
  year = {2018},
  note = {R package version 0.1.0.9842},
  url = {https://github.com/crsh/papaja},
}
```

**Here's the old manual approach**:

[Here](https://gist.github.com/crsh/57874e8e07154aeb43de63f19c2da08f), I chose the `annotation` field in the BibTeX file. I then use the `nocite` field in the YAML front matter to list the works included in the meta-analysis (additional entries need to be separated by `,`).

````
---
title             : "The title"
shorttitle        : "Title"

author:
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"

bibliography      : ["r-references.bib"]
csl               : "apa6-meta.csl"
nocite            : |
  @R-base

output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
---

```{r}
library("papaja")
```

@R-papaja

\newpage

# References

```{r create_r-references}
r_refs(file = "r-references.bib")
```

\begingroup
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.5in}
References marked with an asterisk indicate studies included in the meta-analysis.
<div id = "refs"></div>
\endgroup
````

The edited BibTeX file `r-references.bib` looks like this (note the `annotation` field for `R-base`:

```
@Manual{R-base,
  title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
  author = {{R Core Team}},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  address = {Vienna, Austria},
  year = {2018},
  url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
  annotation = {meta-analysis}
}
@Manual{R-papaja,
  author = {Frederik Aust and Marius Barth},
  title = {{papaja}: {Create} {APA} manuscripts with {R Markdown}},
  year = {2018},
  note = {R package version 0.1.0.9842},
  url = {https://github.com/crsh/papaja},
}
```

Comment: Option 3 worked beautifully - thanks for your very helpful reply!

Comment: Ah, with one exception: The apa6-meta.csl file seems to have broken the internal citations. e.g. "(Bolinger, 1977; Clark, 1987)" now appears as "(Bolinger, 1977)(Clark, 1987)"

Comment: Ah, good catch. I forgot to delete some debugging code. I updated the CSL file, it should now work. If this does the trick for you feel free to upvote and accept the answer. ;)